# How can I assign strings to different elements in an array, sort the array, then display the strings based on the sort in Python/Numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array `P = np.array([2,3,1])` and I want to assign three strings to each element respectively.
So,:

`"str1", "str2", "str3" = P`

and after sorting the array:

```
In[]: P = -np.sort(-P)
Out[]: [3,2,1]
```

I want to then be able to display the strings based on this sort, as:

`Out[]: "str2","str1","str3",`

Tried assigning variable names to the elements but it won't display on output as intended.
Tried defining an array of objects with the strings as elements but have trouble assigning them to the numerical values of P.

Comment: There is no such thing as "*assigning strings*", if you are trying to create dynamic variables know that this is very bad practice (and often useless). What are you really trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.argsort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html).

```
import numpy as np
P = np.array([2,3,1])
S = np.array(["str1", "str2", "str3"])

sort_idx = np.argsort(-P)
print(S[sort_idx])
# ['str2' 'str1' 'str3']
```